AnyLogic Downtime Block Not Starting in Seize Block
I'm working on a simulation model in AnyLogic where I need to introduce a downtime period for cleaning when switching beer types in a cooling tank. I have set up a Downtime block and a Seize block, but the downtime does not seem to start as expected. Below are the details of my setup:
Setup:

Boolean Variable:

isCoolingNewDown to track the downtime status.


Seize Block:

Named NewCoolerseize.
Seizes resource NewCoolerTank.
Code in the On enter section checks if the beer type has changed and triggers the downtime.



if (!currentBeerTypeInNewCooler.equals(agent.BeerType)) {
    System.out.println("Switch in beer type detected. Starting downtime...");
    downtimeCleaningSwitchNewCooler.start(); // Trigger the downtime for cleaning
    System.out.println("Downtime start() called.");
} else {
    System.out.println("No switch in beer type.");
}


Downtime Block:

Named downtimeCleaningSwitchNewCooler.
Configured to handle the cleaning downtime.
Actions on On start and On finish.



// On start
isCoolingNewDown = true;
System.out.println("isCoolingNewDown set to true.");

// On finish
isCoolingNewDown = false;
System.out.println("isCoolingNewDown set to false.");


Resource Pool:

Resource pool NewCoolerTank uses the downtimeCleaningSwitchNewCooler for downtime.



Issue:
The downtime does not start as expected. The print statements in the On start and On finish sections of the downtime block are never executed, indicating that the downtime is not being triggered. Here are some additional details:

The Seize block correctly identifies when the beer type changes and prints the corresponding messages.
The start() method on the downtime block does not seem to initiate the downtime.

What I have tried:

Added print statements around the start() call to ensure it is being reached.

Question:
Why is the downtimeCleaningSwitchNewCooler.start() method not initiating the downtime, and how can I correctly trigger the downtime for cleaning when switching beer types in my cooling tank?

Always use code-complete. Just because you typed downtimeCleaningSwitchNewCooler.start() does not mean it is doing what you think it does. In fact, there is no (supported) .start() method for a Downtime block so you cannot use it. If you use code-complete, you can easily see this:

The downtime block is designed to be started by triggers or schedules, not from a manual method call. So either adhere to what it is designed for or apply a different modelling setup to achieve what you need.
Check out the exhaustive example model demoing how to use the block.
PS: good effort on the question, thx. It is also helpful to add screenshots of properties as we can easily gauge much more than from pure text :)
